# Stack of Plates: Cracking the coding interview , Personal Solution

Tags: java, dictionary, stack, big-o

Stack of Plates: Imagine a (literal) stack of plates. If the stack gets too high, it might topple.
Therefore, in real life, we would likely start a new stack when the previous stack exceeds some threshold. Implement a data structure SetOfStacks that mimics this. SetOfStacks should be composed of several stacks and should create a new stack once the previous one exceeds capacity.

SetOfStacks. push () and SetOfStacks. pop() should behave identically to a single stack (that is, pop ( ) should return the same values as it would if there were just a single stack).

I've implemented a solution with a HashMap.
I'd like to know if this is a good implementation (in space and complexity) and if it can be improve. Moreover, I've used correctly **this.index** ?

```
public class SetOfStacks {

   private final int LIMIT= 5;
   private HashMap<Integer,Stack<Integer>> setOfStack;
   private int index;

   public SetOfStacks(){
       this.setOfStack= new HashMap<>();
       this.index = 0;
   }

   public void addStack(){
       this.index++;
       if(!setOfStack.containsKey(index))
        this.setOfStack.put(index, new Stack<Integer>());

   }

   public void pushElement(int value){
       if (isFull())
           addStack();
       setOfStack.get(index).push(value);
   }

   public boolean isFull(){
       return setOfStack.get(index).size() == LIMIT;
   }


   public void popElement(){
       if(setOfStack.get(index).isEmpty())
           index--;
       setOfStack.get(index).pop();
   }

   public int peekElement(){
       return setOfStack.get(index).peek();
   }

}
```

FOLLOW UP
Implement a function popAt (int index) which performs a pop operation on a specific substack.

I didn't write the solution for it, but i think that his implementation should be easy. I only need to pass the parameter and just manage the push/pop, in case i need to refull that stack or not.
What do you think about maintenance of my code if you need to implement the follow up?

Comment: Please use [codereview.se] if you have a working solution - this site here is primary for solving problems with broken code.

Comment: You already have the index of each sub-stack in the `HashMap`. You can use it to access the last element of any sub-stack. One question does pop in my mind. *If you pop an element from any sub-stack, will the elements from the next sub-stacks in the set shift back?*

Comment: In that case, there are a lot of solution. i thank that i will only set an array of index of Stack to push each item.

Answer (score 1):

It's good but you have some mistake,
you never initialize the first stack,
also what happens if I initialize the `SetOfStacks` and call the pop?(assuming you fixed the first mistake)

Comment: Please add comments if you are providing simple hints or asking for doubts.

Comment: To implement the first stack, it's right to make a new stack in the constructor method?